# Can flowplayer handle rtsp stream?

Tags: android, flowplayer

Flowplayer can play `rtmp` and `http` live stream but can i use the same player to play `rtsp stream`. I have rtsp stream for android which can be played using external player but it opens in fullscreen mode. I thought of putting it inside a frame but the external player opens outside of the frame in android device. So i want to use `flowplayer` to play `rtsp stream` in `android`. Is it possible and if not what to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am fairly certain that Flowplayer, while a great solution for many things, cannot be extended to accept a straight RTSP stream. In any case, I don't believe there is a supported mobile version or plugin of Flowplayer for Android at this point. I have even seen reports that embedded flowplayers being viewed on Android have been sketchy at best.

I have, however, used ffserver and ffmpeg (http://ffmpeg.org/) to transcode the RTSP stream into .flv to be played with Flowplayer, but if a transcoded stream could be broadcast on your system, you'd be well on your way!

Mason

Comment: is there a way to generate *.flv files on the fly with ffmpeg from a rtsp stream? - say in half an hour intervals?

Comment: I assume you've since seen my VLC RTSP post, but I'd think talking about timing should go into it's own question =)